# Omitting elements using custom XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, .net, xmltextwriter

I'm implementing a custom XmlTextWriter and I'd like to omit any elements with a particular name that contain no attributes. I've gotten as far as being able to prevent the element from being written by overriding `WriteStartElement` and `WriteEndElement`, but is there a way to know at `WriteStartElement` or at any other useful point whether or not the element has any attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. However you can postpone writing of the element and attributes (put them in a field) until you get to the next element/comment/etc. Then decide whether you want to write them or not.